# Vue JS - How to get props value in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I have three components **component-1**, **component-2**, and an **App** component, I pass a Boolean props from component-1 to component-2 then using `@click` event I change the props value from true to false and vice versa

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="20%" />
    <component1 />
  </div>
</template>
```

**component-1.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component2 :have-banner="true" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import component2 from "./component-2";
export default {
  components: {
    component2,
  },
};
</script>
```

**component-2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="AssignBanner = !AssignBanner">Click me</button>
    <p>{{ AssignBanner }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    haveBanner: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      AssignBanner: this.haveBanner,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I want to get the value of the props in **component-1**, that is, I want to track the changing value in **component-1**, since I want to write some logic, but I can’t keep track of the value in **component-1**.

You can see the given [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wave-hvmni)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to achieve two-way binding for the prop `haveBanner`. You can achieve this with the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) if you are using Vue 2.3+.

**component-1.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <component2 :have-banner.sync="haveBanner" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import component2 from "./component-2";
export default {
  components: {
    component2,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      haveBanner: true,
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**component-2.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="assignBanner = !assignBanner">Click me</button>
    <p>{{ assignBanner }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    haveBanner: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      assignBanner: this.haveBanner,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    assignBanner(value) {
      // propagate to parent component
      this.$emit('update:haveBanner', value)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you are Vue version < 2.3, you can get the same behavior by replacing ":have-banner.sync="haveBanner"" with '@have-banner="(e)=>this.haveBanner=e"'

Comment: @bricksphd I'm not sure that's right. You still need :have-banner="haveBanner" to pass the prop down. And then you can listen to the \@update:haveBanner event like this: \@update:haveBanner="haveBanner = $event"

Comment: I tried this method, but it does not work, the `haveBanner` value does not change in component-1 when the button is clicked

Comment: @Synchro which version of Vue are you using? The `.sync` modifier is only available in Vue 2.3+

Comment: 99/5000
Translation results
I'm using version 2, even though you mentioned 2.3), but I solved this problem a little roughly. Instead of importing component-2 into component-1, I simply combined these two components, that is, the code that is in component-2 was dragged into component-1